# Get variable name by address

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a dialog that displays an array of bytes, for the purpose of hex editing them. It is possible to switch displayed memory regions. But while some regions are internally arrays, there are a few regions that are structs, and I'm displaying certain elements from them (consecutively).

I want to add a kind of symbolic name feature, where selecting an address gives you its name. For actual arrays it's done by the user, who calls them whatever he wants, and it's saved in file. But those internal structs are not supposed to have user-defined names, instead I want to give them hard-coded names.

The question: is it possible to get their names by knowing their address? Like, byte X of struct Y is referring to the variable Z, when selecting cell X, display it's name as "Z". Or I also have to create name lists and use them regularly?

EDIT:

Simplifying the question: Is there a backward analog of `offsetof()`? Normally you pass it a pointer and a variable, and it gives you the offset to that variable. So I need to pass a pointer and an offset, and get the variable (structure member) name (and then stringify it with `#`).

Comment: Difficult to understand what you are asking here. Use the `&` operator to get the address of an object.

Comment: Pointer and offset is not enough. You need to know the type too. Do you?

Comment: Members of the struct are of 3 different types. Can anything be done about it?

Comment: What is the real problem? How come you ended up with pointers to memory whose type you don't know?

Comment: I know the types of the members, but I output to user the entire struct contains, in bytes (it's only raw data dump, not code). So for any byte he selects, I should know what member it belongs to, and give him the variable name as a string. So yeah, I have a pointer to the entire struct, and user sets the offset, by picking raw bytes.

Comment: If you know the types, you can cast

Comment: Cast a pointer to point to the appropriate type, and dereference it. So if you have an address p that you know is the address of an int, you can write `*(int*)p` to read the value. Or use a C++ cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with making a vector of symbolic name structs (array pointer, start, size, name) and manually adding a bunch of names to it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this as I know it, is to use a map between addresses region and the names.

The code should be something like this :

```
class address_region{
    intptr_t start;
    intptr_t end;

    template<class T>
    address_region(const T& t){
       start = (intptr_t)(&t);
       end   = start + sizeof(t); 
    }

    address_region(intptr_t start_adr=0, intptr_t end_adr=0){
         start = start_adr;
         end   = end_adr;
    }

    bool operator<(const address_region& adr){
        if( adr.start >  start ) return true;
        else return false;
    }
};

map< address_region , std::string > addresses_map;

assume you have this struct;

struct A
{
  int X;
  int Y;
};

A a;

to store addresses it should be something like :
addresses_map[ address_region(a) ] = "struct A";
addresses_map[ addresses_map(a.X) ] = "struct A : int X";
addresses_map[ addresses_map(a.X) ] = "struct A : int Y";
```

to retrieve result:

```
  intptr_t adrs = ....;

  std::string symbole_name = addresses_map[ address_region(adrs) ];
```

Comment: I may be confused (due to little experience), but doesn't your example look like I'd need to manually add items to the list, passing it addresses and names myself?

Comment: Yes depends on this part of the question :
"I want to add a kind of symbolic name feature, where selecting an address gives you its name. For actual arrays it's done by the user, who calls them whatever he wants, and it's saved in file. But those internal structs are not supposed to have user-defined names, instead I want to give them hard-coded names."

Comment: also could you explains to me more what you mean by "
passing it addresses and names myself?"

Comment: I'll try to put it another way. Is it possible, having a pointer and an offset from it, to tell what variable is by that offset in actual program memory? If yes, it exactly solves my issue. Because I don't want to create a map (or whatever it will be) just to list some 100 pairs "emulated cpu variable - hex editor cell".

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler should be able to print a `map` file which is a reference of symbols and their addresses (or offsets).

Looks like you need to create a `std::map` at initialization.  The map would have the symbol's address and the name, something like this:

```
  std::map<uint64_t address, std::string> symbol_dictionary;
```

You will have to perform this at run-time because some operating systems will place your code at different addresses on each execution, depending memory usage by other applications (and memory layout).

I believe you need to change your design, or rethink the requirements.
For example, can you change variables by name rather than by address?
You would display the variable name in the window and allow the user to change the value.  Your program takes this value and sets the variable to this value.  No need to know the addresses.

**For security purposes, you do not want users changing memory by address.**  They could change the wrong address in your program (such as the code in a function), then call you up because your application is not working anymore.

Sorry, but I've got better things to do than support people who type in addresses incorrectly and then wonder why the program doesn't work any more.

Comment: To answer the questions:
- Yes, the user sees the name, and the value he enters goes to the variable. I asked "by address" just because I know it there, and he doesn't.
- I only give things like "emulated cpu registers" to be edited on fly, it's not possible to access anything other than what's in the provided range of memory cells.

Comment: Also, it's not that I _don't know_ the names, and need a mapfile fo get them from addresses. I just need an easier way to give those names to the user, according to which cell he selects. Say, I give some struct to the hex edit dialog, and he randomly sticks to offset $40 in it. It refers to the variable `int Qwerty` in the code, then he must see the text telling it's variable Qwerty that he's selected.

Comment: The problem is that $40 may not refer to the `Qwerty` variable.  Also, the variable may live on the stack, so it can't be easily changed during runtime.  You need to create an `std::map` of <variable_name, variable_address>.  You could iterate through the map displaying all the variables.  When the User changes the value, you lookup the address in the map and write the value to that address.  You may need conversion first.

Comment: No, it always refers to it, because I put regions to hex editor by pointer. So if he selects the cell $40 in the hex editor, it's byte $40 of the array. The same concept it for structs, but also add `&`: `(u8*)&VDP_Reg`. That particular sctuct consists of all ints, so if the user celects cell 5, it refers to the first byte of the second variable in it.